# Why did Zobrist leave a clue?

Tags: plot-explanation, inferno

In Dan Brown's *Inferno*, Zobrist hides a biological hazard in a cavern. But why does he leave a clue (though it's a hard clue) for that place? He had already planted that and he wouldn't want anyone to get a clue of that place.

Dan Brown figured the clue. So why did he take such a risk?